# Consistant hex string to bytestring conversion and output python

Tags: python, output

I am getting odd (seemingly missing/stripped) outputs whenever I try an convert a string (that happens to be hexadecimal values) into a byte string.  (I am stuck with 2.7, tested on linux UTF-8 terminal and windows)

```
>>> from binascii import unhexlify, hexlify
>>> s = '1234beef'
>>> s.decode('hex')
'\x124\xbe\xef'
>>> unhexlify(s)
'\x124\xbe\xef'
```

At first glance it seems that I am dropping outputs:

```
>>> ",".join(unhexlify(s)) #in this case the \x3 is gone
'\x12,4,\xbe,\xef'
```

But it turns out not to be lost, possibly a problem with iteration?

```
>>> hexlify(unhexlify(s)) # \x3 was never lost
'1234beef'
>>> unhexlify(s)=='\x12\x34\xbe\xef'
>>> '\x12\x34\xbe\xef'[1]
'4'
```

It seems to be an output/display problem because writing binary values to a file shows the 3 is still there

```
print '\x12\x34\xbe\xef'[1:3],
# in the file
34be0a
```

This is backed up by taking the ord of each byte

```
>>> [ord(i) for i in unhexlify(s)]
[18, 52, 190, 239]
```

All this leads me to believe there is a problem with the way I am trying to print the bytestrings.

```
>>> str('\x12\x34\xbe\xef')
'\x124\xbe\xef'
>>> repr('\x12\x34\xbe\xef')
"'\\x124\\xbe\\xef'"
```

So how does the python community output to stdout bytestrings as Ascii (or utf)?

Answer (score 1):

As you deduced, everything is working as it should: you've only been caught up by an unusual coincidence.  When Python can show a nicer representation, she does: hence `"\t"` instead of `"\x09"` and `"a"` instead of `"\x61"`.  Or, in your case:

```
>>> ord("4")
52
>>> hex(ord("4"))
'0x34'
>>> chr(ord("4"))
'4'
```

It simply happens that the number 52 (shown in base 10) maps to the digit `4` in ascii, and so Python shows you `"4"` instead of `"\x34"`.

If you'd chosen a different string to work with you wouldn't have thought anything was being dropped, although you might have been surprised at the representation:

```
>>> s ="1256beef"
>>> unhexlify(s)
'\x12V\xbe\xef'
```

Comment: Makes sense, thanks, now I know why it is happening.  As you suspected I am coming across this issue with lots of strings, the ones we mentioned just happened to be short.  Any idea on how to force the raw/expected/escaped behavior?